# VBA - Can I use formulas for calculations with blank cells?

Tags: vba

I want to add to a cell a funcion which addresses to black cells which are going to be filled later.
I have the following code:

```
Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 5).Formula = "=if((" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 4).Value & "-" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 3).Value & ")>0,59;(" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 4).Value & "-" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 3).Value & "-0,4)*100*" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 2) & ";(" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 4).Value & "-" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 3).Value & ")*100*" & Sheets(3).Cells(Kit.Row + 1, Kit.Column + 2) & ")"
```

I get the error message:"application defined or object defined error".

Comment: in vba the formula needs to be entered in as it would be in the united states, using `,` for `;` and `.` for the decimal separator.  Or you can use `.FormulaLocal` which then allows the use of the local style.  But is not portable to other styles.

Comment: @ScottCraner I changed it to .FormulaLocal but I still get the same error. If I use , for ; is it posseble for the funcion to conflict with my excel's local style?

Comment: Save the formula to a text variable then view that variable, does the formula make sense?  can you paste it here?

Comment: @ScottCraner "=if((-)>0.59,(--0.4)*100*,(-)*100*)"
I guess that blank cells are the problem.

Comment: You can't use `Value` to build the formula - you need to use `Address` if you want it to be able to recalculate.